# Redirect stderr only, keep stdout directed to console using System.Diagnostics.Process

Tags: powershell

I am using System.Diagnostics.Process as it allows me to get the error code and associated error.

However, when I set `StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = $false` output is not echoed to my console window, so currently I am forced to add an extra by-ref argument $stdout and echo it from the calling function.

This is not ideal as some commands may generate a huge amount of text, and I am worried about buffer overflows.

Any way that I can still use similar System.Diagnostics.Process code below, still capture errors to string, but let output flow to console normally without redirection to stdout?

```
function Run([string] $runCommand,[string] $runArguments,[ref] [string] $stderr)
{
    $p = New-Object System.Diagnostics.Process
    $p.StartInfo = New-Object System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo;
    $p.StartInfo.FileName = $runCommand
    $p.StartInfo.Arguments = $runArguments
    $p.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = $true
    $p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = $true
    $p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = $false
    $p.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = $false

    $p.Start() | Out-Null
    $p.WaitForExit()

    $code = $p.ExitCode
    $stderr.value = $p.StandardError.ReadToEnd()

    # what I have been doing is using a stdout by-ref variable and echoing out contents
    # $stdout.value = $p.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd()

    return $code
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You may not need to use the System.Diagnostics.Process object.  Just execute the EXE and scoop up the info like this:

```
$stdout = .\foo.exe 2> fooerr.txt
Get-Content fooerr.txt
return $LastExitCode
```